# Frontend Plugin for Eclipse Che doesn't start

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, eclipse-che, theia

I am trying to start a plugin using Hosted Instance but it doesn't seems to work.
Errors doesn't seem to be much helpful.
I am trying steps from here.
https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/contributor-guide/testing-che-theia-plug-ins/
Below is the error log which appears at the start-up.

````
    at e.mapLanguageIdToTextmateGrammar (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:3497957)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2811997
    at x (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2809617)
    at n (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2811926)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812322 

2020-09-15 13:49:28.883 root WARN Error: a registered grammar configuration for 'cpp' language is overridden
    at e.registerGrammarConfiguration (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:3498628)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812121
    at x (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2809617)
    at n (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812042)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812322 

2020-09-15 13:49:28.893 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.html]: Language for 'source.smarty' not found. 

2020-09-15 13:49:28.901 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.markdown]: Language for 'meta.embedded.block.vs_net' not found. 

2020-09-15 13:49:28.905 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.markdown]: Language for 'meta.embedded.block.dosbatch' not found. 

2020-09-15 13:49:28.935 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.markdown]: Language for 'meta.embedded.block.coffee' not found. 
2020-09-15 13:49:28.937 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.markdown]: Language for 'meta.embedded.block.objc' not found. 
2020-09-15 13:49:28.938 root ERROR [1716a64d-8a50-49bb-a3b2-de067a8c6868][vscode.markdown]: Language for 'meta.embedded.block.scala' not found. 
2020-09-15 13:49:28.940 root WARN Error: 'php' language is remapped from 'source.php' to 'text.html.php' scope
    at e.mapLanguageIdToTextmateGrammar (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:3497957)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2811997
    at x (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2809617)
    at n (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2811926)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812322 
2020-09-15 13:49:28.941 root WARN Error: a registered grammar configuration for 'php' language is overridden
    at e.registerGrammarConfiguration (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:3498628)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812121
    at x (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2809617)
    at n (https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812042)
    at https://static.developers.redhat.com/che/theia_artifacts/theia.744bb16ff737c55c6224.js:1:2812322 

2020-09-15 13:49:32.394 root ERROR Failed to load plugins: Params: Error: Unknown actor PluginRemoteNode
    at e.doInvokeHandler (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:124257)
    at e.invokeHandler (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:124116)
    at e.receiveRequest (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:123404)
    at e.receiveOneMessage (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:122891)
    at https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:120881
    at https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:124761
    at https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:8:286522
    at e.invoke (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:8:286741)
    at e.fire (https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:8:288796)
    at https://serverp22s4fgy-theia-idehlt-server-3130.192.168.0.108.nip.io/worker-ext.4ba0e8b1595595965d31.js:1:66253```
````

Comment: Just for You out there - You're not alone. I am stuck with the same issue. Funny enough - the plugin works for me on Theia browser example, but I can't get it to work as Che plugin. Did you find anything since posting this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please open an issue in https://github.com/eclipse/che/? You will get more attention and some of the developers will surely help you there ;-)